# Java AVL tree pointer manipulation

Tags: java, avl-tree

I'm having trouble implementing an AVL tree in java and would appreciate your help,
preferably by explaining what's wrong with my code (I've seen different implementations and would like to figure out what's wrong with mine).

```
public class AVLTree<T> {

public AVLNode<T> root; 

int size;

//constructor
public AVLTree() {
    root = null; 
    size = 0;
}

public void add(T obj) {

    //initialize the new node
    AVLNode<T> node = new AVLNode<T>(obj);

    //if the tree is empty than our new node will serve as a root
    if(root == null)
    {
        root = node; 
        size++;
        return;
    }

    add(root, node);


}

private void checkViolations(AVLNode<T> node) {

    int dif = Math.abs(height(node.left) - height(node.right)) ; 

    //there's a violation at our level 
    if(dif > 1) 
    {
        rebalance(node);
    }

    //if we're at the root, tree is balances(AVL) 
    if(node.parent == null) return; 

    //we're not at the top, check parent 
    checkViolations(node.parent);

}

private void rebalance(AVLNode<T> node) {

    //right subtree is bigger than left subtree
    if(height(node.right) - height(node.left) > 1)
    {
        //problem is right-right
        if(height(node.right.right) > height(node.right.left))
            node = leftRotation(node);

        //problem is right-left
        else 
            node = rightLeftRotation(node);
    }

    //left subtree is bigger than right subtree
    else 
    {
        //problem is left-left
        if (height(node.left.left) > height(node.left.right))
            node = rightRotation(node);

        //problem is left-right
        else 
            node = leftRightRotation(node);

    }

    if (node.parent == null) 
        root = node; 

}

private AVLNode<T> rightLeftRotation(AVLNode<T> node) {

    node.right = rightRotation(node.right);
    return leftRotation(node);
}

private AVLNode<T> leftRightRotation(AVLNode<T> node){

    node.left = leftRotation(node.left);
    return rightRotation(node);
}

private AVLNode<T> rightRotation(AVLNode<T> node) {

    AVLNode<T> temp = node.left;

    node.left = temp.right;
    
    temp.parent = node.parent;

    temp.right = node;

    node.parent = temp;

    return temp;

}

private AVLNode<T> leftRotation(AVLNode<T> node) {

    AVLNode<T> temp = node.right;

    node.right = temp.left;
    
    temp.parent = node.parent;

    temp.left = node;
    
    node.parent = temp;

    return temp; 


}

private int height(AVLNode<T> node) {

    //base case
    if(node == null) return 0;

    return 1 + (Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right)));

}

private void add(AVLNode<T> parent, AVLNode<T> newNode) {

    if(((Comparable<T>)newNode.data).compareTo(parent.data) > 0)
    {
        if(parent.right == null)
        {
            parent.right = newNode;
            newNode.parent = parent;
            size++;
        }
        else add(parent.right, newNode);
    }
    else 
    {
        if(parent.left == null)
        {
            parent.left = newNode;
            newNode.parent = parent;
            size++;
        }

        else add(parent.left, newNode);
    }
    checkViolations(newNode);
}
}
```

I'm trying to add the next numbers in this order (left to right): 1,2,3,4,5

up until 4, everything seems to go great.

Thank you

Comment: and what is it that doesn't seem to go so great?

Comment: the problem seems to be pointer manipulations. first identified when adding the 5

Comment: edited the code, still doesn't work